# Comoving Volume Calculation

Tags: observational-astronomy, cosmology, distances, redshift

Suppose I have data from an astronomical survey at redshifts in the range $z = [2,3]$. Suppose that, on average in this range, the data covers an area on the sky of $A=1$ $\mathrm{Mpc}^2$. How would I calculate the comoving volume covered by the survey? Is it as simple as calculating the comoving distance from $z=2$ to $z=3$ and multiplying by the average area? That is: $V_C = A(D_C(3)-D_C(2))$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That depends on how accurate you want your answer.

The reason is that the angle $\theta$ spanned by a length $L = 1\,\mathrm{Mpc}$ depends on the distance $d$ of that length — in comoving coordinates, $\theta$ keeps decreasing with $d$, just like a normal item, say a bicycle, looks smaller the farther away it is (curiously, in *physical* coordinates, this is not the case. Due to the finite speed of light and the expansion of the Universe, galaxies only look smaller out a certain distance, after which they start to look larger).

An $(L = 1\,\mathrm{Mpc})^2$ square spans $\theta_2 = 39''$ at a redshift of $z=2$, and $\theta_3 = 32''$ at $z=3$. The comoving distances are $d_2 = 5.3\,\mathrm{Gpc}$ and $d_3 = 6.5\,\mathrm{Gpc}$, respectively.

So yes, *roughly* you can say that the comoving volume of an $A = 1\,\mathrm{Mpc}^2$ square between $z=2$ and $z=3$ is $V = A(d_3-d_2)$. But read on.

#### The calculation

You mention a survey, so I assume you're not actually given an area, but a field of view (FOV). The problem is the same, just the other way; your FOV doesn't cover the same area at different redshifts.

So, here's the rigorous way to calculate it:

Let's say your FOV spans a solid angle $\Omega=\theta_\mathrm{RA}\times\theta_\mathrm{dec}$, which measured in radians comprises a fraction $\Omega/4\pi$ of the whole sphere. The total, comoving volume to a comoving distance $d$ is just $V = 4\pi d^3/3$, so the volume of the shell between $z=2$ and $z=3$ is
$$
V_\mathrm{2\rightarrow3} = V_3 - V_2 = \frac{4\pi}{3} \big(d_3^3 - d_2^3\big).
$$

The comoving volume spanned by your FOV is thus
$$
V = \frac{\Omega}{4\pi} V_\mathrm{2\rightarrow3},
$$
or
$$
V = \frac{\Omega}{3} \big(d_3^3 - d_2^3\big).
$$

[image: comvol]

#### The error

The difference between the two approaches increases with the difference between the two redshifts. With a FOV of, say, $\Omega = (\theta=32'')^2 = 1024\,\mathrm{arcsec}^2=2.4\times10^{-8}\,\mathrm{sr}$, if you say that it spans an area of $A = 1\,\mathrm{Mpc}^2$ (which is only correct at $z=3$), you'll get
$$
V_\mathrm{approx.} = 1\,\mathrm{Mpc}^2 \times (6508 - 5312)\,\mathrm{Mpc} = 1198\,\mathrm{Mpc}^3,
$$
whereas with the correct formula you get
$$
V_\mathrm{true} = \frac{2.4\times10^{-8}}{3} \left( 6508^3 - 5312^3\right)\,\mathrm{Mpc}^3 = 1011\,\mathrm{Mpc}^3,
$$
that is, 16% percent lower.

If, on the other hand, your FOV is $\Omega = (\mathbf{39}'')^2$, and if you say that it spans an area of $A = 1\,\mathrm{Mpc}^2$ (which is only correct at $z=\mathbf{2}$), then the true volume would be 1500 Mpc, i.e. 25% larger than your ~1200 Mpc.

Since the correct calculation isn't much harder than the approximation, I suggest you stick to the correct one.

#### The Python way

With the `astropy` module, just type

```
from astropy.cosmology import Planck15
from astropy import units as u
theta_RA  = 32 * u.arcsec
theta_dec = 32 * u.arcsec
Omega     = (theta_RA * theta_dec).to(u.steradian).value # get rid of unit
d2        = Planck15.comoving_distance(2)
d3        = Planck15.comoving_distance(3)
V         = Omega/3 * (d3**3 - d2**3)
print(V)

1011.0148201494444 Mpc3
```

or

```
V23  = Planck15.comoving_volume(3) - Planck15.comoving_volume(2)
V    = Omega/(4*pi) * V23
```

which gives the same result.

Comment: +1 for great explanation and showing the coding option!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation!

Comment: @Framazu You're welcome :)